# openssl smtp email client no email sent

Tags: linux, openssl

I am trying to send email through openssl using script shown below but it quits after showing certificate, login and pwd are correct.

```
#!/bin/bash

username="engrmasood2002@gmail.com";
password="mypassword";
emailFrom="engrmasood2002@gmail.com";
emailTo="maabbasi@iba.edu.pk";
subject="MySubject";

openssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect smtp.gmail.com:587 -crlf <<EOF
helo
auth login
$(echo $username | base64)
$(echo $password | base64)
mail from:$emailFrom
rcpt to:$emailTo
Data
From: $emailFrom
To: $emailTo
Subject: $(echo $subject)

$(< body.txt)
.
EOF
```

The output only is this and no email is sent. I have shown last few lines of output

```
 SSL handshake has read 3113 bytes and written 466 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 256 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Session-ID: 128122902648ECB1A0C92D2BCD02F7D6CCC25D61A6531A43A316045B387D380A
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: A5307264BA8A784FF3D031048A0EA2FE0109AA5DA2F79BAE9765AF45F15997A89B0E98796C4E5FE4E2E524FC98E7E3A3
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 100799 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 01 ff e1 cc a1 bb 7d 31-13 14 0b 78 c4 b1 bd ec   ......}1...x....
    0010 - 3c 3c cc de 1e 9b a1 b2-60 2a 01 85 b5 76 53 e3   <<......`*...vS.
    0020 - 31 b7 30 83 8e 88 3a cc-32 67 6b 1b d7 fe ca 69   1.0...:.2gk....i
    0030 - a9 a1 33 ae 86 24 71 4b-2b 87 88 9b 50 ce 04 63   ..3..$qK+...P..c
    0040 - 0f b0 e4 6c b3 ea f3 44-81 72 2f e3 e8 e4 66 d2   ...l...D.r/...f.
    0050 - 93 25 b6 19 5b 37 58 8d-a3 40 82 22 00 74 7f f4   .%..[7X..@.".t..
    0060 - d6 28 87 0c b3 46 ca 15-bd 19 fb f0 45 a5 30 e0   .(...F......E.0.
    0070 - 97 99 e4 6d ac a5 8a 28-53 1a d5 4e 4d b5 1b a3   ...m...(S..NM...
    0080 - de 51 d2 a4 a7 f5 fe 1e-a3 2d 02 3e c5 e3 25 b1   .Q.......-.>..%.
    0090 - f1 54 19 cd 6f e0 be 05-fd 3f 59 e2 b6 a1 8a 51   .T..o....?Y....Q
    00a0 - eb 83 4c e9 05 2a 43 e9-41 68 5f da d2 23 20 8e   ..L..*C.Ah_..# .
    00b0 - 36 8c 1f 67 33 84 28 2f-f9 b3 98 6b 0d 11 d9 41   6..g3.(/...k...A
    00c0 - 25 bc b0 93 b0 67 49 c6-6e 9b 5f 1d 30 2e 22 f3   %....gI.n._.0.".
    00d0 - 3a f1 d3 ca 12 fe 2a fc-3a 3f c7 75 f8            :.....*.:?.u.

    Start Time: 1611343135
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
```

Comment: It would be better to use `ssmtp`, I think, than trying to synthesise ESMTP yourself. For starters be aware that your username and password have (almost certainly) unwanted newline characters included in them, which will be breaking the authentication

Comment: I ran this command echo $username | base64 but didn't find any new line. The output is a single line for both echo $username | base64 and echo $password | base64.  Anyways Can you tell what command to use to remove line break, if any

Comment: i also tried  echo -n $username | base64 and  echo -n $password | base64  for removing newline character but no success